# Wordpress how can I tell if an active plugin is actually being USED by the site?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I promise you I have tried (and tried) to search for this one but the problem is the only results I get are the blatantly obvious answers (like checking the status in the admin panel). This is not what I mean by my question. Let me explain...

I inherited this site and it has 32 active plugins running. The site is experiencing issues with sending the Gravity Forms notification emails when a visitor submits a form on the site. The form submission is being logged (it shows in the entries table) but the notification emails are not getting sent (and they aren't ending up in spam or mimecast either).

I suspect the issue is a conflict with all the plugins that are active but since I inherited the site, I really have no clue if all the active plugins are actually being utilized by the site.

Is there a way to check if a plugin is actually being USED, not just if it's active but if somewhere on the site it's actively being used. I am a relative new comer to Wordpress development so maybe there's some obvious way but I can't find it and Google has let me down.

Thanks.

Comment: "I suspect the issue is a conflict with all the plugins that are active" - one easy way to find out: disable all plugins except for Grativy Forms and try using the form again. If the email is sent then you'll know for sure that there's a conflict with another plugin, otherwise you'll have to keep digging. (Don't try this on the live website though, should do it either on a staging server or on localhost.)

Comment: I thought of that but the problem is I do not have a staging server for this one. I'm forced to work on their live site. I may still disable them all and just REALLY fast test the form to see what happens.

Comment: If that's the case then give the [Health Check & Troubleshooting](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/) plugin and its [Troubleshooting mode](https://make.wordpress.org/support/handbook/appendix/troubleshooting-using-the-health-check/#troubleshooting) a go. It will allow you to do stuff on the website without affecting what visitors see on the front-end.

Comment: About your questions being moderated, personally I'd have phrased this particular question differently. Something like "Grativy Forms can't send emails, how can I check if it's a conflict with another plugin?" That'd make it clear that you're trying to figure out a programming issue and are looking for suggestions on how to debug the problem. Also, when asking questions here it's always a good idea to let people know what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

[Query Monitor](https://hu.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) is a very useful plugin for debugging.

The `Hooks & Actions` panel shows you the functions used by each plugin.

The `Queries > Queries by Component` panel shows you the database queries that were executed by each plugin.

But there is also an email logger and email tester plugin, if you have specific problems sending emails as described, I recommend these:

[Lana Email Tester](https://wordpress.org/plugins/lana-email-tester/) is a plugin to try WordPress email sending function.

[Lana Email Logger](https://wordpress.org/plugins/lana-email-logger/) is a debugger plugin that logs all emails sent by WordPress.